# How to hide bottom tab navigator when scroll up the screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way to hide the bottom tab navigator when you scroll up the screen?

I have attempted to use route params to set tabBarVisible to false but I think it is not working because I have nested navigator. In other words, my tab in my tab navigator is another stack navigator.

In my bottom tab navigator I tried doing this...

```
Tab1: {
        screen: OtherStack,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
          const routeParams = navigation.state.params
          return {
            tabBarVisible: routeParams && routeParams.tabBarVisible,
            tabBarIcon: ...
            }
          }
        },
      },
```

Then in my OtherStack I use createNavigator to create a screen like this...

```
NewScreen: {
    screen: NewScreen,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
     return {
       headerTitle: <Header />,
       headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6'},
       headerLeft: null,
     }
    }
```

Then as a test, in the NewScreen I am calling a function via touchableOpacity onPress...

```
onPress={() => navigation.setParams({ tabBarVisible: false })}
```

But nothing happens. I want to get this to hide the tab bar when I click the button, and after I get that to work I want to call that function onScroll.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: According to the documentation you can provide custom tab bar component. In this custom component you can implement all the animations and goodies you want. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html